# htaccess: Replace /filename.asp?FOO to /new/folder/FOO

Tags: asp.net, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create 301 .htaccess redirects and having a hard time figuring out how to do the redirect/rewrite properly.

For example, here is the **original url:** http://domain.com/filename.asp?abc

Now want that to be: http://domain.com/new/folder/abc

How?

The only thing that I got working was this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} abc$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /new/folder/abc? [R=301,L]
```

But that isn't efficient and is only specific to the the item after the ?
I have several queries and repeating the above isn't really efficient.

Tried to google this several times but each redirect I found were regarding ?whatever=param

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Lea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/filename\.asp$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?([^&]+)&?
    RewriteRule ^filename.asp$ new/folder$1/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Then when I did the 301 redirect I just did it like so:

```
Redirect 301 /new/folder/abc /new/folder/longer-url-string
```